# Не видит рендер как исправить

Tags: javascript, canvas, three.js

Ошибка

> Uncaught TypeError: _loaders.render is not a function
>       at loaders.js:131

сам код:
https://jsfiddle.net/hsydbhea/

вот прошлая тема [Отображение obj/stl объектов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/618305) там код чуть чуть другой,но проблема такая

```
_loaders.render();


      _loaders.render = function () {
_loaders.orbitControls.update(_loaders.clock.getDelta());
_loaders.requestAnimationFrame(_loaders.render);
_loaders.webGLRenderer.render(_loaders.scene, _loaders.camera);
   };
```

на сайте просто черный экран

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Этот код не работает, так как сперва идет использование и только потом объявление.

Вот так будет правильно:

```
_loaders.render = function () {
    // add code
};

_loaders.render();
```

Рекомендую ознакомится со статьёй «[Область видимости в JavaScript и «поднятие» переменных и объявлений функций](https://habrahabr.ru/post/127482/)».

Comment: теперь такая ошибка
>Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'update' of undefined
    at Object._loaders.render (loaders.js:136)
    at loaders.js:140

Comment: @Michael  так  `_loaders.orbitControls` не объявлен, нужно вызвать перед `render` я полагаю `_loaders.loadCurrentObject`

Comment: я вот это скрипт под себя переписывал
https://jsfiddle.net/yozmrb74/

Comment: loaders.js:137 Uncaught TypeError: _loaders.requestAnimationFrame is not a function
    at Object._loaders.render (loaders.js:137)
    at loaders.js:142